# Visual Studio 2015 Unit Test IntelliTrace Results

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, intellitrace

Where would I find the results saved by IntelliTrace for a unit test in Visual Studio 2015? I checked IntelliTrace in the testsettings file, but can't figure out where I should look to see anything IntelliTrace captured.

I found some links like this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6hl8txBGcc), but the "View Results" window in VS2015 doesn't show any results for unit tests.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firsly, make sure that unit testing engine uses your test setting file. To do so:

1. Select *Test* menu from the toolbar.
2. *Test Settings* -> *Select Test Settings File*
3. Navigate to your file and select it.

Now, you can run your tests. Then select a test that has failed. In the details, just below a message you will see *Output* link. Click it.

[image]

You should see something like that:

[image]

In the *Attachment* group box there is your IntelliTrace log.

You can also find IntelliTrace logs in *Test Results* directory. By default, it is located in the root of a solution.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! I must have missed something before.

Comment: Any chance you can explain how to do this with VS2017? The test settings editor does not exists on VS2017 and I can't find the full reference to manually create it and configure intellitrace